# What did Harry Truman think about the 25th Amendment to the US Constitution?

Tags: united-states, president, constitution

The American Presidential succession process is interesting in that it starts off in the executive branch (with the VP), moves to the legislative branch (Speaker of the House, then President Pro Tem), then moves back to the executive to each cabinet officer from oldest to most recent creation of the department. In looking at this state of affairs, I learned that President Truman wanted it this way:

> Insofar as possible, the office of the President should be filled by
>   an elective officer. There is no officer in our system of government,
>   besides the President and Vice President, who has been elected by
>   all the voters of the country. The Speaker of the House of
>   Representatives, who is elected in his own district, is also elected
>   to be the presiding officer of the House by a vote of all the
>   Representatives of all the people of the country. As a result, I
>   believe that the Speaker is the official in the Federal Government,
>   whose selection next to that of the President and Vice President, can
>   be most accurately said to stem from the people themselves.

[Feerick (1995)](https://ir.lawnet.fordham.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1382&context=faculty_scholarship)

And Truman's wishes were enshrined in the [Presidential Succession Act of 1947](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/19). The [25th Amendment / Amendment XXV](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/amendments-11-27) revisits some of these issues, like enshrining that the Vice President must be the first in order of succession, creating the process of filling a vacant office of Vice President, and mandating procedures for handing presidential incapacity other than death, and was ratified in 1967 while Truman was still alive.

What did he think about the 25th Amendment? What are sources that provide further details on Truman's thoughts on the 25 Amendment?

Comment: Hekko, and welcome to History.SE. Please note that links are transient, and related info from them should be, at least in brief, be included in the question. In other words - could you expand a bit on the " 25th Amendment revisits some of these issues" part?

Comment: This feels like an **X-Y problem**: an inquiry into a proposed and unsupported solution Y for an unspecified problem X. Please either explain why anyone would care what Truman thought of the 25th amendment, or what the real problem is that this question is attempting to sidle into being a solution for.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, I don't entirely understand your comment, but Truman assumed the office of US President after the death of FDR and so lived through the old process. He then pushed congress to amend the old succession process to the form that ended up enshrined in law.  Therefore, as a historically important person, who dealt extensively with and was a leader on related issues, it is natural to wonder if he ever discussed his thoughts on subsequent developments in the same policy area.

Comment: I'm not sure if Truman ever commented on the 25th amendment after it was adopted, but - as [this paper](https://ir.lawnet.fordham.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1382&context=faculty_scholarship) by John D. Feerick makes clear - he certainly participated in the '_debate and discussion leading to the amendment's adoption_'.